# Using conditions on tuples within sub arrays within an array

Tags: python, tuples, conditional-statements, arrays

```
A = [[(1,2,0),(3,4,0),(5,6,0)],[(7,8,1),(9,10,1),(11,12,1)],[(13,14,0),(15,16,0),(17,18,0)]]
```

I'm having problems attempting to sum the third element from each tuple inside a given sub array and then applying some condition to it. i.e. the output from the above is desired to be:

```
B = ['X',(7,8,9,19,11,12),'X']
```

Here is what I'm currently doing. Note that the number of tuples will vary but the number of elements inside each is constant.

```
i = 0
while i < len(A):
    if sum([X[2] for X in A[i]]) == 0:
        B.append('X')
    else:
        arr = [x[0:2] for x in A[i]]
        B.append(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arr)))
    i = i+1
```

The specific problem I was after with multiple statements has been solved and is of the form:

```
A = [[(1,2,0),(3,4,0),(4,5,0)],[(6,7,1),(8,9,1)],[(10,11,0)]]
B = ['X' if not sum(t[2] for t in sub) and len(sub) >= 2 else tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(t[:2] for t in sub)) for sub in A]
print B

['X', (6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11)]
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that was an error - I've changed it now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's straight up not navigating correctly.

Comment: WTH does "straight up not navigating correctly" mean? Aside from the fact that I get a list (which you *explicitly* ask for) rather than a tuple as shown, I get the output you say you want.

Comment: I don't understand the question either. I see no difference except the one @jonrsharpe mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
['X' if not sum(t[2] for t in sub) else tuple(i for t in sub for i in t[:2])
 for sub in A]
```

Demo:

```
>>> A = [[(1,2,0),(3,4,0),(5,6,0)],[(7,8,1),(9,10,1),(11,12,1)],[(13,14,0),(15,16,0),(17,18,0)]]
>>> ['X' if not sum(t[2] for t in sub) else tuple(i for t in sub for i in t[:2])
...  for sub in A]
['X', (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 'X']
```

or, if you really still want to use `itertools.chain()`:

```
from itertools import chain

['X' if not sum(t[2] for t in sub) else tuple(chain.from_iterable(t[:2] for t in sub))
 for sub in A]
```

Again, as a demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> ['X' if not sum(t[2] for t in sub) else tuple(chain.from_iterable(t[:2] for t in sub))
...  for sub in A]
['X', (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 'X']
```

Comment: Nice! One more question that I can't figure out from your solution:
How to add multiple conditions to the first if statement:
i.e. if not sum (t[2] for t in sub) and len(of that sub array) <= 2:...

Comment: it is a conditional expression; you can add multiple conditions using  the usual boolean expressions to the `if` test.

Comment: `if not sum(t[2] for t in sub) or len(sub) <= 2` perhaps?

Comment: A = [[(1,2,0),(3,4,0),(4,5,0)],[(6,7,1),(8,9,1)],[(10,11,0)]]
    B = ['X' if not sum(t[2] for t in sub) and len(sub) >= 2 else tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(t[:2] for t in sub)) for sub in A]
    print B
    ['X', (6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11)]

Perfect!

Comment: Damn formatting screwed up!

Comment: Don't count on much formatting in comments then. :-) I got the gist..

Comment: @user3394391: there is no need to share the final code you came up with; you can still mark an answer that helped you as accepted instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use the first two tuples in each sub-list for your output, you will need to be explicit about that:

```
arr = [x[0:2] for x in A[i][:2]]
```

**Edit** for some reason you apparently now *don't* want just the first two. The rest still stands:

---

More generally, a list comprehension would be neater here:

```
 B = [tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(t[:2] for t in l)) 
      if sum(t[2] for t in l) else 'X' for l in A]
```

This gives me the result you say you want:

```
>>> B
['X', (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 'X']
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for shifting the goal posts a bit!